# SFML add to sf::String?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I've been using SFML lately and I was wondering how I could "add" to sf::String.

For example:

```
sf::String exampleText;
exampleText.SetText("I say: ");
exampleText += "Blah";
```

Result: "I say: Blah"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sf::string doesn't offer an append method which makes sense as it's intended to be a class for the graphical display of text rather than a traditional string class.

So you have to perform your string manipulation/append operations behind the scenes using your usual char array/string/stringstream classes and then call sf::string::SetText to update it.

Comment: *headdesk* People tell me I need more sleep. I should start listening to them. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, and I know the feeling :D

Answer (score 3):

```
sf::String exampleText;
exampleText.SetText("I say: ");
std::wstring toAppend(L"Blah");
exampleText.SetText(exampleText.GetUnicodeText() + toAppend);
```

Try that. I have never used `sf` though.

`GetUnicodeText` returns `std::wstring`. And by using the `+` it may work. Try it.

OR (now that I saw the sf docs better)

`exampleText.SetText(exampleText.GetText() + "Blah");`

`GetText()` returns std::string
`SetText()` Accepts both `wstring` and `string`

Comment: -1 Because GetUnicodeText() is (obviously) not a member of sf::String. ;)